# controller not visible in swagger API page

Tags: spring, java-8, swagger

I recently migrated my app to Java 8. A controller I wrote is not visible in swagger API page. Other controllers appear on that page and cause no problems.

A warning appears in logs:

```
WARN reflections.Reflections: could not scan file /path/MyController.class with scanner TypeAnnotationsScanner
  org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not create class file from MyController.class
  Caused by: org.reflections.ReflectionsException: could not create class file from MyController.class
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: invalid constant type: 18
```

swagger4spring-web version 0.3.2

Comment: Have you looked at using http://springfox.io instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of swagger uses org.reflections:0.9.8 to inspect classes, which does not support Java 8 operations, in particular stream operations which you might have used in your new controller.

When you replace stream() operations with standard-pre-8-java operations your controller will be properly loaded.